# Remap Middle Mouse Constraint Mode

Tags: modeling

I love that you can constrain to an axis using middle mouse during transforms, but I would rather have it on Right Mouse.  I can't find it in the input settings, does anyone know where to find it?

Comment: I don't believe it's in the input settings because you have to be in scaling mode (for example) in order for it to become available.  You could probably add it yourself although I don't know the identifier or the attributes, maybe someone will respond.  For what it's worth, I usually just use the X,Y,and Z keys which selects the specific axis.

Comment: These may be hardcoded unfortunately. While blender is quite flexible and configurable, these might just be beyond the threshold of customization, I'm afraid.

Comment: It's a shame since this is one of the most commonly used functions!

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I spent hours trying to find an answer to this!

Not sure when they added it but it's available in 2.93. Using the search box won't display it, you have to manually drill down:

Preferences > Keymap > Transform Modal Map > Automatic Constraint

[image]